# How to sum a record total and hide if the sum is 0?

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to hide the sum of all weeks that equals to 0. I tried to use window sum as a calculated field, but it didn't work.

```
WINDOW_SUM(ZN([Sum of Failure]))<>0
```

[image]

Comment: What is the "compute using" setting for your calculated field? Try different options

Answer (score 0):

We can't see your row labels so I'm going to use a placeholder name `[Category]`, but this could be solved using a level of detail calculation.

Create a field to be used as a filter, something like `[Total Over Zero]`, replacing the placeholder `[Category`] with whatever field is in the Rows card:

```
{INCLUDE [Category]: SUM([Sum of Failure])} > 0
```

Then place this new field on your Filters card and set to True.

Comment: It didnt work because I have a parameter which is hidding/showing data. Even window sum is not working.

Comment: Again, when you tried the table calc in your original question, what was “compute using” set to? That can work as a filter if you get the “compute using” setting correct. AKA partitioning and addressing, described in the online help for table calcs.